# Mysql query with multiple joins and conditions

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to connect four tables using joints,here i used left join to connect tables and my condition is all the goods,item should be same and all the site should be same.same site have multiple goods, so i want to get the sum number of goods from each table. my query is given

```
select 
    a.goods
    ,sum(a.no_of_units) as totala
    , a.site
    ,b.item
    ,sum(b.quantity) as totalb
    ,b.site
    ,c.goods
    ,c.site
    ,sum(c.no_of_units) as totalc
    ,d.site
    ,d.goods
    ,sum(d.quantity)b as totald 
from 
    inward_stock a 
left join 
    opening_balance b 
on 
    a.site=b.site 
and 
    a.goods=b.item 
left join 
    return_stock c 
on 
    b.site=c.site 
and 
    b.item=c.goods 
left join 
    stock_consumed d 
on 
    d.site=c.site
and 
    d.goods=c.goods
```

Comment: provide schema here so we can help you

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. Is the query not working? Does it give an error? Wrong data?

Answer (score 0):

Can you put your conditions at the end of the joints like this:

```html
select a.goods,sum(a.no_of_units) as totala, a.site,b.item,sum(b.quantity) as totalb,b.site,c.goods,c.site,sum(c.no_of_units) as totalc,d.site,d.goods,sum(d.quantity) as totald 
from inward_stock a left join 
     opening_balance b on (a.site=b.site) left join 
     return_stock c on (b.site=c.site) left join 
     stock_consumed d on (d.site=c.site) where (a.goods=b.item) and (b.item=c.goods) and (d.goods=c.goods)
```

I have not tested your request but it seems that it's not bad.

Comment: let me test your request and tell you what

Comment: what's wrong with your data? Returning duplicated rows or the sum is incorrect?

Comment: sum is incorrect .i tried one more query it is giving double of actual data select a.goods,sum(a.no_of_units) as totala, a.site,b.item,sum(b.quantity) as totalb,b.site,c.goods,c.site,sum(c.no_of_units) as totalc,d.site,d.goods,sum(d.quantity) 

as totald from inward_stock a left join opening_balance b on (a.site=b.site and a.goods=b.item) left join return_stock c on (b.site=c.site and b.item=c.goods ) left 

join stock_consumed d on (d.site=c.site
and c.goods=d.goods ) group by a.goods,b.item,c.goods,d.goods,a.site,b.site,c.site,d.site

Comment: what are your requirements? Because based on my request, I simile by creating a database with the same tables I ready inserted some information, and the query works correctly.

Comment: can you try to remove the **"b"** juste here : `sum(d.quantity)**b** as totald `

Comment: i removed that ,but i am getting double of the actual data